# Import variables from another .py file

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, nameerror

I am learning python programming and I am stuck in something that is probably very basic but I cannot fix.
My problem is: I have a .py file called "Downloading_The_Data" in a directory. This file contains some variables like "HOUSING_PATH" and others. Now, I have another .py file in the same directory and I want to import the other file into it. I simply write "import DOWNLOADING_THE_DATA" and everything works fine except when I try to use the variable "HOUSING_PATH" which seems not imported. The code:

The "DOWNLOADING_THE_DATA" file:

```
import os
import tarfile
import urllib

DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml/master/"
HOUSING_PATH = os.path.join("datasets" , "housing")
HOUSING_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + "datasets/housing/housing.tgz"

def fetch_housing_data(housing_url=HOUSING_URL, housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
    if not os.path.isdir(housing_path):
        os.makedirs(housing_path)
    tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz")
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(housing_url, tgz_path)
    housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path)
    housing_tgz.extractall(path=housing_path)
    housing_tgz.close()
```

The new python file is:

```
import pandas as pd
import Downloading_The_Data

def load_housing_data(housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
    csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path , "housing.csv")
    return pd.read_csv(csv_path)
```

The error is: NameError: name 'HOUSING_PATH' is not defined

I thought I could just import the 'DOWNLOADING_THE_DATA' file and all the variables declared there would be imported so I could use it. Thus, my question is simple and straight: What is wrong and how do I fix it?

edit: just a disclaimer: I know I could use everything in just one file and simply call pandas and everything and load the csv in the same notebook, but it is an exercise I'm doing for myself. I know someday I will need to import other files with its variables and stuff so I am just trying to do this from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use any definitions from another python file like this:

```
import module
module.variable = 5
module.class()
module.function()
```

or You can do:

```
from module import variable, class, function
variable = 5
class()
function()
```

`from module import *` is not good practice.
If you hate typing, you can give another name:

```
from module import variable as var
var = 5
```

Comment: hmm I see. But if I have a LOT of variables is there any easier way to import them all without writing each one I'm importing?
I do not hate typing and I want to write the code as clean as possible using all good practices and everything. But it seems cumbersome to write import var1, var2, var3 etc when I can have 100 variables.

Comment: If you have a hundred variables you should use a list, he/she also mentions that you can use ```*``` (bad practice)

Comment: @Kin4StAt You should mention classes if op has to use ```from module import *```

Answer (score 1):

It's just like every other Python module.

```
def load_housing_data(housing_path=Downloading_The_Data.HOUSING_PATH):
```

If you really hate all that typing, you can do:

```
from Downloading_The_Data import *
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the "dumb" question. I knew it would be something very simple and probably very basic but I was really stucked. This is really my first time. Used the import * and it worked. Thank you very much.
```

Comment: Another question: in the former case, when I write 'def load_housing_data(housing_path=Downloading_The_Data.HOUSING_PATH):' what is the technical name of HOUSING_PATH? I mean, is it now a method inside the module Downloading_The_Data?

Asking because I want to know and use the right jargon when speaking about

Comment: dimitri if you think this answer worked mark it correct, but I will mention @KiN4StAt mentioned it first